# javascript if else construct

Tags: javascript

I'm running through a loop in which I have this code:

```
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            TheVar = "StyleEven";
        }
        else {
            TheVar = "StyleOdd";
        }
```

Is there a "better" way to write this?

Thanks.

Comment: When a million people post examples of the ternary conditional operator, as they're about to, bear in mind that it's not necessarily "better" at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator) `?:`.

```
var style = (i % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd";
```

Comment: Do you need the semi colon at the end of the line?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't require one, but some webbrowsers do. You don't want to be dependent on that.

Answer (score 1):

Terse++ && Cryptic++:

```
var thevar = !(i % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';
```

Comment: Cryptic += 2, then: `var thevar = i & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even';`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many people will have to look there.

If this code is only "for you", the best way to write that is the way you'll be able to read it the most easily ;)

If you're in a team, maybe just ask if there are some code standard in your team and try to follow them.

Answer (score 0):

```
TheVar = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'StyleEven' : 'StyleOdd'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TheVar = i%2==0? "StyleEven" : "StyleOdd"
```